# Django Autocomplete-light with mutiple apps

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I'm using Python 3.4 Django 1.7. My project includes 3 applications that have similar models for example:

I have an ElectricityBill application with:

```
Account, Meter, Invoice models.
```

I also have a NaturalGasBill application with:

```
Account, Meter, Invoice models.
```

When I register my autocompletes, (Same with both applications), the second will always replace the first.. for example.. when I goto localhost/autocomplete I get this:

```
InvoiceAutocomplete     /autocomplete/InvoiceAutocomplete/
AccountAutocomplete     /autocomplete/AccountAutocomplete/
MeterAutocomplete   /autocomplete/MeterAutocomplete/
```

Obviously, there is nothing unique about these urls to indicate which application the url should apply.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the documentation:

```
# Extra **kwargs are used as class properties in the subclass.
autocomplete_light.register(SomeModel,
# SomeModel is already registered, re-register with custom name
name='AutocompleSomeModelNew',
# Filter the queryset
choices=SomeModel.objects.filter(new=True))
```

A link to the documentation is here: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/cookbook.html

Registering the autocomplete with a custome name is exactly what I was looking for. It is unfortunate this was so difficult to find in the documentation.